# How can I disable sounds played by Qt QMessageBox?

Tags: windows, qt

I am working on a Windows application using Qt 4.8 that uses

```
QMessageBox::information
QMessageBox::warning
...
```

When any of thes functions is called, windows plays by default a sound. My customers are annoyed of this and want to disable this permanently without changing windows settings.

How can I get rid if this sound?

I found that it is called from

```
void QAccessible::updateAccessibility()
```

But I do not so far see a way to disable it.

Comment: I think this is a windows feature.

Comment: No, the sound is actively called from Qt.

Comment: I don't think so, QMessageBox says nothing about sound at all, and I am pretty sure I get no sound on a QMessageBox, because I've disabled the windows sound schemes.

Comment: I stepped through the sources in the debugger. The sound is played in void QAccessible::updateAccessibility()

Comment: There is a SoundPlayed component in QAccessible in their documentation. As for messagebox, I know that the static methods of QMessageBox call native message boxes that make sounds. Try making a QMessageBox message, setting it up with its properties, and then calling .exec() on that object. Supposedly can have different results w/ audio. Might be worth trying.

Comment: Why are your customers annoyed only by your messagebox and not by the other system sounds? That's weird. Remember to preserve Accessibility when creating your own messagebox.

Comment: It is a Windows sound. When I disabled sounds in Windows, it is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a different `QMessageBox`, `QMessageBox::about`, or make your own instance of `QMessageBox` and set the [`iconPixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#iconPixmap-prop) and everything yourself, you shouldn't get the beeping noise.

```
QMessageBox::warning(0, "Test", "test"); // Plays alert

QMessageBox::about(0, "Test", "test"); // No sound, but no icon either

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setParent(0);
msgBox.setWindowTitle("Test");
msgBox.setText("test");
if(false)
{
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);// makes sound
}
else
{
    QPixmap p;
    p.load("warning.png");
    msgBox.setIconPixmap(p);// no sound, but with icon
}
msgBox.exec();
```

Otherwise, to disable the warning sound, you probably will need a [global event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#notify) on your app to catch any event/message from `QAccessibility` with the role of `QAccessible::AlertMessage`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You'll also need to call something like `msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);` to get the message-box to display.