# How to mute all sounds (alarm bells) from a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qdialog, mute

**I'm wondering how to mute all sounds from the `QDialog`.** I have this basic popup-window class based on `QDialog`,

```
class PopUp : QDialog
{
    // member vars and funcs
};
```

which I display like

```
PopUp *popup_msg = new PopUp(this, /* ... */);
popup_msg->exec();
```

This PopUp-class doesn't really do anything except displaying some text, but I need it to be modal, hence I call `setModal(true)` in the constructor. The problem is that, when a `QDialog` is modal, it plays an error bell/beep/sound when the user tries to interact with other widgets (e.g. the MainWindow). I want to disable this sound!

This question: [How can i disable sounds played by Qt QMessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070012), addresses the problem but doesn't completely solve it in my case. Its solution only mutes the sound upon `show()`-ing the `QMessageBox` (or `QDialog` in my case), but the sound still plays when the user tries to click on other widgets. I want it muted completely, and one would think this was a trivial problem with a really simple solution. Maybe something like `QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_MuteAllSounds, true)` could have existed, but apperently not(?).

All help, tips and tricks are most appriciated!!

Comment: This behavior is managed by operating system, not by Qt. You need to turn off sounds in your OS (on windows - with control panel).

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I thought so too, at first. However, according to the OP of the question i linked, "(...) the sound is actively called from Qt" and "[He] stepped through the sources in the debugger. The sound is played in void QAccessible::updateAccessibility()"

Comment: You can create your own type of modal windows if you need such deep customization of default OS features. For example, you may disable all other windows without making your popup modal. But you may catch a lot of bugs with user input.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Indeed, I did. See my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631011/).

Comment: If it works - it is good.