# My Qt eventFilter() doesn't stop events as it should

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog

**Something is fundamentally wrong with my eventFilter, as it lets *every* single event through, while I want to stop *everything***. I've read lots of documentation on `QEvent`, `eventFilter()` and so on, but obviously I'm missing something big. Essentially, I'm trying to create my own modal-functionality for my popup-window class based on `QDialog`. I want to implement my own since the built-in `setModal(true)` includes a lot of features, e.g. playing `QApplication::Beep()`, that I want to exclude. **Basically, I want to discard all events going to the QWidget (window) that created my popup**. What I have so far is,

```
// popupdialog.h
#ifndef POPUPDIALOG_H
#define POPUPDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {class PopupDialog;}

class PopupDialog : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PopupDialog(QWidget *window=0, QString messageText="");
    ~PopupDialog();
private:
    Ui::PopupDialog *ui;
    QString messageText;
    QWidget window; // the window that caused/created the popup
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*); // popup closes when clicked on
    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent*);
};
```

...

```
// popupdialog.cpp
#include "popupdialog.h"
#include "ui_popupdialog.h"

PopupDialog::PopupDialog(QWidget *window, QString messageText) :
    QDialog(NULL), // parentless
    ui(new Ui::PopupDialog),
    messageText(messageText),
    window(window)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true); // Prevents memory leak
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    ui->message_text_display->setText(messageText);

    window->installEventFilter(this);

    //this->installEventFilter(window); // tried this also, just to be sure ..
}

PopupDialog::~PopupDialog()
{
    window->removeEventFilter(this);
    delete ui;
}

// popup closes when clicked on
void PopupDialog::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    close();
}
```

Here's the problem, the filter doesn't work. Note that if I write a `std::cout` 
 inside the `if(...)`, I see that it does trigger whenever events are sent to `window`, it just doesn't stop them.

```
bool PopupDialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if( obj == window )
        return true; //should discard the signal (?)
    else
        return false; // I tried setting this to 'true' also without success
}
```

When the user interacts with the main program, a PopupDialog can be created like this:

```
PopupDialog *popup_msg = new PopupDialog(ptr_to_source_window, "some text message");
popup_msg->show();
// I understand that naming the source 'window' might be a little confusing.
// I apologise for that. The source can in fact be any 'QWidget'.
```

Everything else works as expected. Only the event filter fails. **I want the filter to remove events sent to the window that created the popup; like mouse clicking and key pressing, until the popup is closed**. I'm expecting to be extremely embarrassed when someone points out a trivial fix in my code.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the widget?

Comment: Does your code compile? There are some missing semicolons and other mistakes in there. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky I'm sorry. I just wrote the code here a little too fast (removed unimportant parts to make it more readable). YES, the code compiles and runs smoothly and everything is nice, except the filter... I will fix the typos immediately.

Comment: @thuga Yes, using `setEnabled(false)` does work, but I feel it's a little overkill, and I would prefer to use the event filter if possible.

Comment: What if you try to cast `window` to `QObject*` before checking? `if( obj == static_cast<QObject*>(window) )
        return true;`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Thanks, but no, didn't work. Let me emphasise as I commented in the code, that the if-statement does trigger! I can print using `std::cout` whenever it recognises an event from the `window` and it does so correctly. Hence I also tried swapping `true` <--> `fase` just to be certain, but it gave no effect.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall No prob. I'm just really curios why this doesn't work. It has been bothering me for several days now.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually passing the window through to the constructor? (Just a thought... it can't hurt to check) :)

Comment: @VictorTran Interresting suggestion, thanks! I thought for a moment you were right, but unforunately no, it is passed correctly as far as I can see. I am able to call its member fuctions with success via the pointer in PopupDialog.

Comment: See if that event filter is working at all: filter all the events and return false, and install the event filter on QApplication. Do events get stopped?

Comment: How do you create `PopupDialog`? And what kind of events do you want to filter and it doesn't? How do you know that the events are not filtered?

Comment: Maybe your comparing the wrong `QObject*`. If I understand Qt event handling correctly, then some input events will be passed to the leaf in the widget tree, i. e. to the smallest subwidget of `window` that you can get. If the event is ignored by it, then it is passed to the next level up the hierarchy and so forth. Only if all the children in the hierarchy ignored the event, then will `window` actually get to handle it.

Comment: I played around and noticed that setting an event filter for PopupWindow in MainWindow works and prevents all events from propagation to PopupWindow. But MainWindow gets all events despite PopupWindow's event filter sees them. Maybe there's something to do with an event loop, just a suggestion

Comment: Victor Tran, vahancho Ralph Tandetzky and lena, Thank you all so much for your suggestions! Yes, you are in fact right. The filter doesn't work at all, even though it sees the events. After reading some other questions with similar problems, I'm led to believe that there is another built-in `eventFilter()` at work, which catches the events and realizes them before my filter gets to stop them. Some tutorials I've found states that `QApplication::notify()` might be reimplemented in order to discard _every_ single event to a `QObject`. I'm currently looking into that.

Comment: @Magnus In this case you might install an event filter on the `QCoreApplication` instead of overriding `QCoreApplication::notify`. This is much cleaner, because the event filter will be unregistered automatically when it is deleted.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Thanks, I'll check that out after going through the details of the answer that just popped in.

Comment: @lena I found your observation really interresting. It seemes to me (even though I'm just a fresh beginner with Qt), that the `eventFilter()` is really intended for the `parent` widget to monitor the `child`, for which is what is mostly being considered by the vast majority of examples out there. However, when ones tries to make a `child` monitor a `parent`, or the two `QObjects` aren't related at all (which was my case), then the issue becomes really complicated. I wish there was more details and examples on this kind of problems.

Comment: @KubaOber Well, I'll have to disagree with you. **Could you pelase specify what you mean by "without providing any [implementation]"?** Because, it is there at the bottom: It seems to me that you haven't fully really read my question and the code I provided. Please do so first. Also, I've already read and attempted the solution you link to, both by making all child widgets transparent and the eventfilter-approach in the answer. Neither worked.

Comment: @KubaOber I've concluded that the problem was as Ralph explained, that the events are caught by the child widgets and were responded to before they are caught by the parent for which the eventfiler is installed. If you have a better solution, I'll be happy to hear it!

Comment: Your snippet happened to render exactly such that the scrollbars were invisible and the `eventFilter` implementation was right below the visible part of the window. I've edited it to make that code stand out on its own.

Comment: You do not want to discard all events, not at all. Some of the events are critical to maintain the coherent state of the widgets. You want to prevent interaction with the widget tree, and for that all you need is to filter out mouse, touch, gesture and keyboard events **after ensuring that the state is such that you can do so safely**. E.g. if you start filtering while a key is held down, you're corrupting the state as the key release will never be received. And so on - paint events must not be filtered, or hide/show events, etc. So it's not as simple of a problem as you think.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you very much for improving my question, that is most appriciated! All I want to contribute to the community, and also solve some of my own problems on the way. I've found what I believe to be the _correct_ (or least wrong) solution/approach which I posted and _accepted_ below. I'd really appriciate your opinion on it! Feel free to edit that too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to ignore all events that arrive in the widget tree of the `window`. Therefore, you need to install the `eventFilter` application-wide and check, if the object you are filtering on is a descendant of `window`. In other words: Replace

```
window->installEventFilter(this);
```

by

```
QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(this);
```

and implement the event filter function this way:

```
bool PopupDialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if ( !dynamic_cast<QInputEvent*>( event ) )
        return false;

    while ( obj != NULL )
    {
        if( obj == window )
            return true;
        obj = obj->parent();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried it, tested it and it worked for me.

**Note:** Using event filters in Qt is a bit messy in my experience, since it is not quite transparent what is happening. Expect bugs to pop up from time to time. You may consider disabling the main window instead, if you and your clients don't have a problem with the grayed-out main window as a consequence.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Thank you so much! It works.. Damn, I'm been stressing over this for far too long. I just love this community. Indeed I'll need to do some serious testing to ensure that things goes right. I'll also reconsider `setEnabled(false)` again. I agree that this approach needs to be treated with serious caution. But for now, it works. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Ok. I added two lines in the `eventFilter()` function. Only `QInputEvents` are filtered now. This prevents filtering events that should not be messed with.

Comment: I've found a solution I believe is somewhat safer, which is posted below. I'd really appriciated your opinion on it!! Thank you so much for all your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

After the massive amount of responses, feedback, suggestions and time ivested in extensive research I've finally found what I believe to be the optimal, and safest solution. I wish to express my sincere gratidtude to everyone for their aid to what Kuba Ober describes as "(...) not as simple of a problem as you think".

**We want to filter out all certain events from a widget, *including its children*.** This is difficult, because events may be caught in the childrens default eventfilters and responded to, *before* they are caught and filtered by the the parent's custom filter for which the programmer implements. The following code solves this problem by installing the filter on *all* children upon their creation. *This example assumes the use of Qt Creator UI-forms and is based on the following blog post:* [How to install eventfilters for all children](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.no/2014/04/qt-get-child-controls-events.html).

```
// The widget class (based on QMainWindow, but could be anything) for
// which you want to install the event filter on, includings its children

class WidgetClassToBeFiltered : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WidgetClassToBeFiltered(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~WidgetClassToBeFiltered();
private:
    bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*);
    Ui::WidgetClassToBeFiltered *ui;
};
```

...

```
WidgetClassToBeFiltered::WidgetClassToBeFiltered(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), // Base Class constructor
    ui(new Ui::WidgetClassToBeFiltered)
{
    installEventFilter(this); // install filter BEFORE setupUI.
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

...

```
bool WidgetClassToBeFiltered::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent* e)

{    
    if( e->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded ) // install eventfilter on children
    {
        QChildEvent *ce = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(e);
        ce->child()->installEventFilter(this);
    }
    else if( e->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved ) // remove eventfilter from children
    {
        QChildEvent *ce = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(e);
        ce->child()->removeEventFilter(this);
    }
    else if( (e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) ) // e.g. filter out Mouse Buttons Relases
    {

       // do whatever ..
       return true; // filter these events out
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter( obj, e ); // apply default filter
}
```

**Note** that this works, because the eventfilter installs itself on added children! Hence, it should also work without the use of UI-forms.

Comment: Sure, it's a solution. It probably slows down the application just as much as my solution would do (not very much, but never the less). I'm a bit concerned, if the events to all children's children will be filtered though. Imagine a widget which gets your widget as a parent, but already has some children. The event filter will not be installed upon the already existing children, unless you further change your code. That makes the solution even longer and more complicated. It also has a poor separation of concerns, because you change your `MainWindow` to make your dialog work the way you want.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Thanks! Your comments are really valuble to me! Hence, you still believe using `setEnabled(false)` is the better solution?

Comment: My experience with event filters in Qt is that it is messy from time to time. Often you cannot transparently see what's going on and you have to fix bugs that pop up from time to time. Since my solution doesn't filter all events, but only `QInputEvents` it appears somewhat safe. Disabling the main window looks cleaner to me still, yet it is not exactly what you want (as far as I understand). It depends, if you can live with a somewhat ugly grayed-out main window under your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code to filter out specific event:-

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow();

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev);

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    setCentralWidget(textEdit);

    textEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == textEdit) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            qDebug() << "Ate key press" << keyEvent->key();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // pass the event on to the parent class
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

If you want to set more specific event filter on multiple widgets you can refer following code:

```
 class KeyPressEater : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 protected:
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
 };

 bool KeyPressEater::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
 {
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         qDebug("Ate key press %d", keyEvent->key());
         return true;
     } else {
         // standard event processing
         return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
     }
 }


 KeyPressEater *keyPressEater = new KeyPressEater(this);
 QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
 pushButton->installEventFilter(keyPressEater);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Unfortunatley, I've already tried this approach, and it is almost exactly alike what I originally posted, except for that you return another `eventFilter()` instead of just `false` for unfiltered events. Ralph's answer (above) solved my issued, but I really thank you nevertheless for taking the time to try to help me!