# Why is ShortcutOverride not preventing QML from receiving key press?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm having a problem understanding how handling keyboard press events works in Qt/QML. In the following code I have a Navigation_Control class that installs an event filter on qApp and implements the eventFilter function to handle the Enter/Return key event. Then, in the QML, I have a Rectangle element with a Keys.onPressed handler. When the application is launched and the Enter key is pressed, both the QEvent::ShortcutOverride (in C++) and the Keys.onPressed handler (in QML) are being run, causing the console to print out:

```
Key_Return - ShortcutOverride
qml: Enter key pressed on child
```

This is unexpected. The QEvent::ShortcutOverride is calling event->accept() and returning true. Why is the Keys.onPressed handler in QML still recieving the Enter key press event after is has already been handled by the QEvent::ShortcutOverride in the eventFilter function?

```
class Navigation_Control : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Navigation_Control(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);
    bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) override;
};

Navigation_Control::Navigation_Control(QQuickItem* parent)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
{
    qApp->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool Navigation_Control::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride)
    {
        QKeyEvent* key_event = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (!key_event)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int key = key_event->key();
        if (key == Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            std::cout << "Key_Return - ShortcutOverride" << std::endl;
            event->accept();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

// main.qml

```
Window {
    id: main_window
    width: 900
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Navigation_Control {}

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "blue"
        focus: true

        Keys.onPressed: function(event){
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Return)
            {
                console.log("Enter key pressed on child")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does installing an event filter help? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631011/my-qt-eventfilter-doesnt-stop-events-as-it-should

Comment: You probably got confused by the fact that shortcut is something else than key press in Qt. I think that your code does exactly what is documented in `QEvent::ShortcutOverride`. Accepting the event in event filter causes to process the pressed key as keypress instead as shortcut. Docs: "When a shortcut is about to trigger, ShortcutOverride is sent to the active window. This allows clients (e.g. widgets) to signal that they will handle the shortcut themselves, by accepting the event. If the shortcut override is accepted, the event is delivered as a normal key press to the focus widget."